# for (var key in object) in CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

How can I use for (var key in object) in CoffeeScript? It compiles to...

```
for (_i = 0, _len = object.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    key = object[_i];
```

...but I just want to iterate though an object.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

`for key of object`

Try it in [js2coffee](http://js2.coffee/)

Comment: Also note the `own` keyword to enforce `hasOwnProperty` ... `for own key of object`

Comment: Just for anyone else that comes by, it's the `of` keyword that determines looping through arrays vs. objects.

Answer (score 72):

`of` keyword:

```
for key, value of obj
```

or to make sure you're only checking properties on this object (and not the prototype chain):

```
for own key, value of obj
```

Comment: the point of that website is to a) see how I can do a js pattern in coffeescript and b) convert existing js files to coffeescript without re-writing them.